# AdonisJS, como fazer um update de várias tabelas com apenas um await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs

Estou aprendendo a trabalhar com [AdonisJS](https://adonisjs.com/) e encontrei várias formas de fazer update, mas gosto sempre da maneira mais performática, depois de ler vários artigos e a documentação cheguei ao seguinte código:

```
async update ({ params, request }) {
    const dados_aluno = request.only(['nome','cpf','dt_nascimento','peso',
                                      'altura','sexo_id','tipo_sanguineo_id'])
    const dados_endereco = request.only(['cep','endereco','numero','bairro','cidade','uf'])
    const dados_contato = request.only(['email','telefone','celular'])
    await Database.table('alunos').where('id', params.id).update(dados_aluno)
    await Database.table('enderecos').where('aluno_id', params.id).update(dados_endereco)
    await Database.table('contatoes').where('aluno_id', params.id).update(dados_contato)
}
```

Funciona, mas gostaria de fazer os três updates com um await apenas, é possível?

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço adonis, dando mais uma resposta genérica...

Relembrando que o que o `await` faz é "desenrolar" a resposta de um objeto do tipo `Promise<T>`.

```
const x = await y  //onde y possui tipo Promise<Algo>
// x possuirá o tipo "Algo"
```

O código abaixo faz praticamente a mesma coisa, só que sem a sintaxe do await.

```
y.then( x => {
  console.log(x)
})
```

Quando uma Promise é finalizada e dá o seu resultado no "then", fala-se que ela "resolveu" ou "rejeitou" (no caso de erro).

A função `Promise.all` recebe um array de Promises e retorna uma nova Promise que só é *resolvida* depois que todas as promises entradas tiverem sendo resolvidas. Ela pode ser usada pra chamar coisas em "paralelo". Ela retorna no seu .then um array das respostas das promises de entrada.

```
[Promise<X>, Promise<Y>, Promise<Z>] --> Promise.all --> Promise<[ X, Y, Z ]>
```

Então você escreveria algo como

```
await Promise.all([
  Database.table(...),
  Database.table(...),
  Database.table(...)
])
```

Agora aqui uma observação. Se esses seus dados possuirem um relacionamento no banco de dados (por exemplo, se o endereço que você quiser adicionar pertencer ao aluno), o Adonis possivelmente terá alguma sintaxe pra fazer a inserção de objetos relacionados com um comando só, pois é um recurso comum em ORM's.

Comment: Sim há um relacionamento e eu consegui fazer num único await o select all e o create mas  o update ainda não encontrei, mas vou continuar estudando o framework pois ele é lindo. Realmente não entendo tanto de Promises e já vou estudar mais sobre elas, valeu pela resposta.